# Example Petrov Classification

Tags: linear-algebra, general-relativity, tensor

I would like to calculate the Petrov type for a specific spacetime, unfortunately I am not able to find a step by step algorithm or example for the process, either using null-tetrad, nor calculating the often denoted Q-Matrix from the Weyl-Tensor. Is anyone able to point me towards a detailed example?

Comment: I take it you are working in four dimensions?  If so, there are the so-called Bel criteria; although you need to be able to calculate the Weyl tensor.  There is a 1962 paper of Bel's in French, which was reprinted in English translation in Gen. Rel. Grav. 32 (2000) 2047.

Comment: unfortunately I dont seem to have access to that paper.

Comment: Here you go: https://www.dropbox.com/s/brlxrxs0nb6o982/Bel2000_Article_RadiationStatesAndTheProblemOf.pdf?dl=0